# Why doesnt throwing an XAException from a XAResource still allow an transaction commit to succeed?

Tags: java, transactions, jta, xa

I am trying out a few things w/ JOTM and have some general purpose questions regarding how things work. I have listed the sequence of events to get a definitive summary of what happens.

1. create tx
2. enlist resource
3. tx.commit
4. resource.start
5. resource.end throws XA EXCEPTION
6. resource.commit

Even if the resource.end throws a XAException the tx commit will still work which seems plain wrong to me. Whats the point of throwing an exception if it doesnt mark the tx as rolled back ...

Do all tx managers work like this or does throwing an XAException fail the tx ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TM behaviour depends not just on the existence of an XAException but on the XAException error code. Any of the (spec compliant) XA_RB∗ codes thrown from end should cause a rollback.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding of XA, ALL kinds of XAExceptions thrown during prepare MUST lead to rollback of the XA transaction.

HTH.

Thanks,
Nitin